# How to specify function signature for function that returns result of async?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that does this:

```
??? createThread(int x) {
   return async(std::launch::async, 
      [x] () { // do stuff with x });
}
```

I am using VS 2012 (partial C++11). What should the return type be to make this compile?

Comment: Does "partial C++11" include support for `auto createThread(int x) -> decltype(EXPRESSION)`? I mean, it would be ugly, but you could basically just copy the `return` expression into the `decltype` check there and let the compiler figure it out.

Comment: I tried that at first, but it said that lambdas are not allowed to go into an expression that is not evaluated (decltype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a `std::future<void>`: the future result of the call of the asynchronous function.

However, it is very poor practice to return a future returned from a call of `std::async` with the `std::launch::async` policy, as such a future's destructor may block, and users of the standard library usually don't expect standard library destructors to block. Cf. [futures.async]/4:

> [*Note:* If a future obtained from `std::async` is moved outside the local scope, other code that uses the future must be aware that the future’s destructor may block for the shared state to become ready. — *end note*]

Comment: IIRC VS2012's `async` returns a non-blocking future :)